# Selenium Button not clickable

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

After passing the username and password, I'm trying to click on the login button.
username and password insert properly but it is not clicking the "login" button and fail the test. There are two login buttons that exist with different LinkText and I was able to capture the specific login button by following XPath.

```
"//button[contains(string(), "Login")]"
```

This is the error message that I'm getting

> Step failed
> Element is not clickable

I have tried the below solutions as well but didn't work any of them

```
  1st Method 

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.linkText("Login")));
// click on the compose button as soon as the "compose" button is visible
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login (en)")).click();
    <a href="http://LOGGER.info" target="_blank">LOGGER.info</a>("clicked return on a button");
    
2nd Method 

WebDriverWait myWaitVar = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
WebElement el = myWaitVar.until(ExpectedConditions._elementToBeClickable_(By._xpath_("//button[contains(string(), "Login")]")));
<a href="http://el.click" target="_blank">el.click</a>();

3rd Method 

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By._linkText_(" Login "));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element).click().build().preform();
```

Comment: Post the url to have a look. In the '2nd Method', you mentioned the xpath as: "//button[contains(string(), "Login")]", which is wrong. It should be - "//button[contains(string(), \"Login\")]".

Comment: Thanks, AbiSaran  it worked I have used JavascriptExecutor and then it worked Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update xpath as below. If this also does not work with normal click, try using java script executor.

"//button[contains(text(), 'Login')]"